# fread() doesn't work but fwrite() works?

Tags: c, file, file-io, fwrite, fread

**Why `fread()` doesn't work but `fwrite()` works?**

If I get `fwrite()` into comments and `fread()` out of comments, the output file is of `0 bytes` size... But if `fwrite()` is out of comments, the output file is of `64 bytes` size..

What is the matter?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *input = fopen( "01.wav", "rb");

        if(input == NULL)
        {
            printf("Unable to open wave file (input)\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    FILE *output = fopen( "01_out.wav", "wb");


    //fread(output, sizeof(char), 64, input);
    fwrite(input, sizeof(char), 64, output);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: Besides reading from your input file, and writing to your output file, where are your buffers?

Comment: @user315052: Oh, I've forgot.. What a stupid mistake!... Thanks for the mention.

Comment: @CarlNorum, I know. I want to copy 1*64 bytes.

Comment: That's fine.  `sizeof(char)` just looks weird, since it can always be replaced either by `1` or something with better semantics.  Check out @user315052's answer for a good example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read from your input file, and write to your output file.

```
char buf[64];
fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), input);
fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), output);
```

Your code should check the return values of `fread` and `fwrite` for errors.

Comment: The two lines of code work together. `fread()` line is reading from input into the buffer. `fwrite()` is writing the contents of the buffer to the output.

Comment: Your `fwrite` never "worked" the way it was. You passed in `input` as the first parameter, but `fwrite` is not reading from `input` the file stream, it was treating `input` as a pointer to the data to be written. `input` and `output` are pointers to data structures in memory which describes how to read and write things from and to the file system to their respective files. Your `fwrite` was writing out this data structure, not the contents of the input file on the file system.

Answer (score 1):

```
fread(output, sizeof(char), 64, input);
```

This line will read 64 bytes from the input file and store those 64 bytes at the memory that `output` points to. It will not write anything to the output file. Since `output` is a file pointer and not a pointer to an array, it does not make sense to use it like this.

```
fwrite(input, sizeof(char), 64, output);
```

This line will read 64 bytes from the memory that `input` points to and write them to the output file. It will not read anything from the input file. Again this won't do what you want since the memory that `input` points to simply contains a `FILE` object and not the contents of the input file.